# Virtual Microphone setup (eg. play mp3 into the microphone port)

Tags: microphone, recording

Is there a way to stream audio into the microphone port without jacking the speaker audio cable into the mic port?  Operating systems: Windows, Linux

Comment: you wouldn't want to use a mic jack anyway -- it's powered, you want line-level.  you'd use a line-in jack.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want a *virtual* solution -- for example, you want a) to use some software to play an MP3 on a computer, and b) to use some *other* software to record that audio output *on the same computer*, you want something like [**JACK**](http://jackaudio.org/):

> JACK ... can connect a number of different applications 
>   to an audio device, as well as allowing them to share 
>   audio between themselves. Its clients can run in their 
>   own processes (ie. as normal applications), or can they 
>   can run within the JACK server (ie. as a "plugin").

See the [JACK FAQ](http://jackaudio.org/faq) for how to use it, and the [JACK download page](http://jackaudio.org/download) to get the source tarball; a Windows installer is included.  For Linux, your distribution's software repositories (*apt-get*, *yum*, etc) already include JACK binaries, so you can use your preferred package management tool to install it.

On Ubuntu, you want to install the packages "jackd", "jack-tools", and possibly "qjackctl":

```
sudo apt-get install jackd jack-tools qjackctl
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 has the ability to play an mp3 player through the mic port to speaker. I think they call it microphone listening or something. You could probably record from the mic port then.

EDIT: see this link [Lifehacker.com.au](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2009/07/play-your-ipod-through-your-windows-7-pcs-speakers/)